# How do us SetActive to turn off a group of GameObjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 4 buttons.  Each buttons will turn on a Game Object and will turn off the other three.

Is there a better way to do it than what I have below.

```
public void Button1() {
    gameObject1.SetActive(true);
    gameObject2.SetActive(false);
    gameObject3.SetActive(false);
    gameObject4.SetActive(false);
}

public void Button2()
{
    gameObject1.SetActive(false);
    gameObject2.SetActive(true);
    gameObject3.SetActive(false);
    gameObject4.SetActive(false);
}

public void Button3()
{
    gameObject1.SetActive(false);
    gameObject2.SetActive(false);
    gameObject3.SetActive(true);
    gameObject4.SetActive(false);
}

public void Button4()
{
    gameObject1.SetActive(false);
    gameObject2.SetActive(false);
    gameObject3.SetActive(false);
    gameObject4.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say so, yes.  Create an array of the button game objects and cycle through that list.  I am assuming you set-up the button associations within the Editor:

(untested)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class YourClass : MonoBehavour
{
    public GameObject gameObject1;
    public GameObject gameObject2;
    public GameObject gameObject3;
    public GameObject gameObject4;
    private List<GameObject> _buttons = null;

    void Start()
    {
        _buttons = new List<GameObject>();
        _buttons.Add(gameObject1);
        _buttons.Add(gameObject2);
        _buttons.Add(gameObject3);
        _buttons.Add(gameObject4);
        // Other stuff
    }

    public void Button1()
    {
        TurnOnButton(0);
    }

    public void Button2()
    {
        TurnOnButton(1);
    }

    public void Button3()
    {
        TurnOnButton(2);
    }

    public void Button4()
    {
        TurnOnButton(3);
    }

    private void TurnOnButton(int buttonNumber)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _buttons.Count(); i++) {
            _buttons[i].SetActive(i == buttonNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I did do the associations.  Thanks for this!